# Python: Can't run code after pressing shift+enter in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I run python 3.7 in vscode in a conda environment. I do switch between jupyter notebook `.ipynb` and regular python `.py`

The problem I face takes place after pressing `shift enter` in a regular `.py` file. What happens is that the interpreter places a `&` as first character of the python path, which leads to a `Synthax Error`.

When I accidently press `shift enter` running a `.py file` I have to restart vscode in order for the terminal to work again.

This path is displayed by the terminal running the `.py` file with no problems.

```
PS C:\Users\luuk\Desktop\Scripts\Archive\Archive> conda activate base
PS C:\Users\luuk\Desktop\Scripts\Archive\Archive> & C:/Users/luuk/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/python.exe "c:/Users/luuk/Desktop/Scripts/Archive/Archive/Python/Pipelines/azdl_adb_chunks.py"
```

This is what is shown after pressing `shift enter` in `.py` file

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> & C:/Users/luuk/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/python.exe "c:/Users/luuk/Desktop/Scripts/Archive/Archive/Python/Pipelines/azdl_adb_chunks.py"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Users/luuk/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/python.exe "c:/Users/luuk/Desktop/Scripts/Archive/Archive/Python/Pipelines/azdl_adb_chunks.py"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Haven't found this issue on stack so your advise is more than welcome!

Comment: hey can you add a snippet of the error that you see? i know a bug in vscode debugger with running python. not sure if that's same as yours.

Comment: I added some snippet

Comment: You can exit the python shell using `exit()` instead of restarting vscode.

Comment: @SuperStormer thank you very much this saves a lot of time !!!

Comment: You can also change the keyboard shortcut in File->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts. I think it should be Python: Run Python File in Terminal, but I'm not sure as I changed mine already.

Comment: @SuperStormer Thats sweet, fixed it so no longer being able to press shift enter in .py file only in .ipynb